# Prevent developers from making concurrent DB changes

Tags: database, migration, liquibase

Recently we've had an incident whereby two engineers made changes to the same DB table. The changes were not conflicting i.e. they could both be executed in sequence successfully without failures. However, one meant the second would no longer be valid, or work as expected. This was an oversight from an engineer who did not spot a new change was introduced.

My questions is around best practices to make sure this does not happen again. We use Liquibase, where there is a notion of changeset IDs. At the moment we used the format `V2000.01.01.1000__description_of_change`.

One way to mitigate this is to have an  auto-increment standard for changeset IDs e.g. 1, 2, 3 and so on. This means that if another engineer was to merge a migration whilst you are testing, you would get a conflict and would be required to at the very least check what has been introduced. Is this the best way to avoid this scenario, or are there any other suggestions or tools that I'm missing?

Comment: I guess that integration test should verify if liquibase changes are applied correctly.